# Using preg_replace to add quotes to array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace

I have this array:

```
$array = '[[Smarties, 50g, 3, 1.99], 
          [M&Ms Peanut, 49g, 3, 1.99], 
          [Oreo Cookies, 300g, 1, 3.99], 
          [Pepsi, 355ml, 3, 1.29]]';
```

I need to use json_decode, so I need to find a way to surround the information inside in quotes like this:

```
[["Smarties", "50g", "3", "1.99"], 
["M&Ms Peanut", "49g", "3", "1"."99"], 
["Oreo Cookies", "300g", "1", "3.99"], 
["Pepsi", "355ml", "3", "1.29"]]
```

I tried using preg_replace, and this is what I'm currently getting (close, but it's separating the prices into two and also separating two-word names into two.):

```
[["Smarties", "50g", "3", "1"."99"], 
["M"&"Ms" "Peanut", "49g", "3", "1"."99"], 
["Oreo" "Cookies", "300g", "1", "3"."99"], 
["Pepsi", "355ml", "3", "1"."29"]]
```

I'm having a really hard time understanding preg_replace and I'm hoping someone might be able to help.

Is there a way to use the separating commas as guides to determine where to put the quotes?

Comment: You can use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) such as `(?<=\[)` or `(?!\s*\()`. Though it might be easier to look for consecutive non-commas and brackets and exclude surrounding whitespace, then wrap in quotes.

Comment: You should share the regex you already have. It should help you get an answer faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a somewhat crude, but context-aware regex one could use:

```
$str = preg_replace("~ [\[\],\s]*\K [^,\[\]]+ ~x", '"$0"', $str);
                           ↑             ↑
                        skip ][,    capture non-
                        + space   commas/brackets
```

Where the charclass before `\K` skips structural characters, and the second `[…]` only finds anything but commas and brackets - which then is wrapped in quotes.

Comment: While this could be extended, it's only meant for the sample input. (Rewriting requests will be ignored.)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

One not optimal, but working example:

```
$result = json_decode(strtr(strtr($yourString, array('['=>'["', ']'=>'"]', ', '=>'","', ']","['=>'],[')), array(']","[' => '],[', '["[' => '[[', ']"]' => ']]')), true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Process this string, something like,

```
$sample = explode('],', $array);

foreach ($sample as &$v)
{
    $v = array_map('trim', explode(',', trim($v, '[ ]')));
}
```

Now, array becomes,

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Smarties',
    1 => '50g',
    2 => '3',
    3 => '1.99',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'M&Ms Peanut',
    1 => '49g',
    2 => '3',
    3 => '1.99',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Oreo Cookies',
    1 => '300g',
    2 => '1',
    3 => '3.99',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Pepsi',
    1 => '355ml',
    2 => '3',
    3 => '1.29',
  ),
)
```

Simply, `json_encode()` will give,

```
string '[["Smarties","50g","3","1.99"],["M&Ms Peanut","49g","3","1.99"],["Oreo Cookies","300g","1","3.99"],["Pepsi","355ml","3","1.29"]]' (length=128)
```

Comment: You also need to have `"` inserted at the start and end of the string as well

Comment: yes, absolutely, you are right, check the update @Machavity